# Removing emoticons from Instagram captions in PHP

Tags: php, regex, instagram, emoticons

Does anyone know to strip the emoticons from instagram captions?  I subscribe to their api for feeding certain photo types and display them on my website.  I tried used the command below in PHP to strip out emoticons with no success.

```
    $newcaption  = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \.]/s', '', $caption);
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of instagram emoticons using PHP? I have no idea what their ascii character set is.

Comment: I agree, these things are a pain. Instagram does not strip them out when displaying them on their web site. They look horrible on their web display as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instagram does not have native emoticons. My suggestion is, create an array with all known emoticons (emoji, Android, iOS, etc) and than search and remove them from the `$caption`.

I don't see other way to do it.

Update:

I have written a regex that could help you without creating the array, but it can lead into some mistakes. Try and watch the results, here it is:

```
$pattern = '/((?=:)|(?=;))(.*)(?=\s{1,})/i';
preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
```

Comment: What names do I use to identify the emoticons or other special characters?  Is there a table of character sets I can refer to for emoticons?

Comment: I didn't search in google, but I think that should be a list with the most used emoticons. But the regex I posted will give you a good help.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  I will try your code and see if it eliminates any of the emoticons.